# no operator matches these operands c++

Tags: c++, cin

```
my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str1[1000000];
    char newString[1000][1000]; 
    int i,j,ctr;
       cout <<" \n\n Split string by space into words :"<< endl;
       cout << "---------------------------------------\n";    

    cout << " Input  a string : ";
    cin >> str1 >> sizeof(str1) >> stdin;   

    j=0; ctr=0;
    for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
    {
        // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
        if(str1[i]==' '||str1[i]=='\0')
        {
            newString[ctr][j]='\0';
            ctr++;  //for next word
            j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j]=str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n Strings or words after split by space are :\n";
    for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
        cout << newString[i];

    return 0;
}
```

The error statement:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'unsigned int' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   c:\users\ayah atiyeh\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\source.cpp  14
>     3   IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operands
>               operand types are: std::basic_istream> >> unsigned int   c:\Users\Ayah
>   Atiyeh\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cpp  14

Comment: Why are you not just using `std::string`? BTW - What do you think the line `cin >> str1 >> sizeof(str1) >> stdin; ` means?

Comment: Where should I use std:: string please?

Comment: `>> sizeof(str1)` what?

Comment: Use std::string for strings. Use std::vector for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
cout << " Input  a string : ";
cin >> str1;
```

instead of :

```
cout << " Input  a string : ";
cin >> str1 >> sizeof(str1) >> stdin;
```

The thing is, >> operator is used to direct an input to the variable on the right of it.
And you are not giving a variable on the right of second >>, sizeof(str1) is a function and it returns a number. and when the compiler sees a number in place of a variable, it gives you that error.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char str1[1000000];
```

to

```
std::string str1;
```

And

```
cin >> str1 >> sizeof(str1) >> stdin;
```

to

```
std::cin >> str1;
```

BTW - Remove the line `using namespace std;`

Then the line

```
 for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
```

should be

```
  for(i=0;i<str1.length();i++)
```

Comment: Or since C++11 `for(char c : str1)` :)

Comment: Error 1 error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'unsigned int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\ayah atiyeh\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\source.cpp 13

Comment: 3 IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>> >> unsigned int c:\Users\Ayah Atiyeh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cpp 13

Comment: std::cin >> str1 >> sizeof(str1) >> stdin;  in this line

Comment: @A.Atiyah that is one of the lines that you were told to replace - why do you still have it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> str1 >> sizeof(str1) >> stdin;
```

In the second part of this input statement, you're trying to read into an **rvalue** (`sizeof(str1)` is a compile time constant and is an rvalue). You shouldn't do that. Also reading something to `stdin` is a dangerous operation as its type is `FILE*`, which may negatively affect further input operations.

Comment: How to change it?